# Boy's faces crushed with a millstone as coming-of-age ritual: short story identification

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Please help me identify a short story.

In the story, there is a village in which the coming-of-age ritual for men involves crushing their faces with a millstone.
The boy lays his head under the millstone, and the millstone is lowered until it breaks the nose and the bones of the face.
The protagonist, a boy whose time has come, runs away from the village to keep his face, but is convinced by his father to return and have his face crushed, who claims that other villages have equally awful traditions.

I probably heard this through a fantasy / sci-fi podcast, perhaps Podcastle or StarShipSofa, or something adjacent, sometime around 2010-2014.

I've Googled this every way I can think of, with no luck, so thank you for your help!

The story was fantasy insofar as it was set in a fantasy land (not Earth) with medieval technology. But, there wasn't any magic or anything of that sort I can recall.

Comment: Eugh.  Sounds like a wonderful place to live.  Individual villages each having their own bizarre rituals sounds like something out of Lawrence Watt-Evans' [*The Annals of the Chosen*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Annals_of_the_Chosen) though I don't remember that ritual specifically.

Comment: Besides, breaking any other bones after the nose would almost definitely mean the cheek (zygomatic) and maxillary bones get broken.  Given a low-tech society, if most of the men aren't blind it's _definitely_ a fantasy...